# Default value for column postgres function with argument

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a postgres function that takes one argument. I want to make this function the default value for a column, but I'm not sure how to pass the argument into the table definition.

This is what I mean, I have two columns in the table that look like this:

```
trade_id INTEGER NOT NULL
group_id INTEGER DEFAULT trade_id_f(argument_goes_here);
```

I want to make the `DEFAULT` value of `group_id` to be the return value of `trade_id_f(trade_id)` where `trade_id` is the `trade_id` of the record to be inserted.

I'm new to all things postgres functions, is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that, because of (for [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html)):

> The value is any variable-free expression (subqueries and
>   cross-references to other columns in the current table are not
>   allowed).

You can use a trigger, e.g.:

```
create table the_table (
    trade_id int not null,
    group_id int);

create or replace function trade_id_trigger ()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    new.group_id:= new.trade_id+ 1;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger trade_id_trigger
before insert or update on the_table
for each row execute procedure trade_id_trigger();

insert into the_table values (1,1);

select * from the_table;

 trade_id | group_id
----------+----------
        1 |        2
(1 row)
```

Comment: Is it still possible to use a custom function as a default expression if this function does not refer to any table and does not require any argument?

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland - You can use a custom function with no or constant arguments as a default expression.