# How can I set a default for column B to be the value in column A in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How can I set a default for column B to be the value in column A?

I know, it is possible in **Microsoft SQL Server**:

http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2010/04/19/default-column-value-to-identity-of-different-column/

Is it possible in **PostgreSQL**?

Comment: You cannot do that, see: [Default value for column postgres function with argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32183363/default-value-for-column-postgres-function-with-argument/32184436#32184436).

Comment: Hmmm, well I would leave it as null and use Coalesce(col_b, col_a) to select it

Comment: Out of interest ... why would you want to do that? What're you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked example shows how to intialize one column with the value of the identity column of the same table.

That is possible in Postgres

```
create table identdefault
(
    a serial not null,
    b int not null default currval('identdefault_a_seq')
);
```

`serial` will create a sequence in the background that is named `tablename_column_seq` thus we know that the sequence for `identdefault.a` will be named `identdefault_a_seq` and we can access the last value through the `currval` function.

Running:

```
insert into identdefault default values;
insert into identdefault default values;
insert into identdefault default values;

select *
from identdefault
```

will output:

```
a | b
--+--
1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 3
```

This seems to only work with Postgres 9.4, when I tried that with 9.3 (on SQLFiddle) I got an error. But in that case it is possible as well - you just can't use the "shortcut" `serial` but need to create the sequence explicitly:

```
create sequence identdefault_a_seq;

create table identdefault
(
    a int not null default nextval('identdefault_a_seq'),
    b int not null default currval('identdefault_a_seq')
);


insert into identdefault default values;
insert into identdefault default values;
insert into identdefault default values;
```

If you want to have an identical definition as with the `serial` column, you just need to make the sequence belong to the column:

```
alter sequence identdefault_a_seq owned by identdefault.a;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0aa34/1

---

The answer to the much broader question "*How can I set a default for column B to be the value in column A?*" is unfortunately: **no**, you can't (see klin's comment)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with an actual `DEFAULT`, but it's trivial with a `BEFORE` trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION whatever() RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.onecol := NEW.othercol;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER whatever_tg
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE whatever();
```

Answer (score 1):

"You cannot do that" and postgres don't go well together. There's almost always a way you can do that (whatever "that" turns out to be).

The question is more like: How do you want to do it?

One way, that is nice to DB-Admins would be: Create a before-Trigger, manipulate the new row before it is written.

If your rules to create that new column are very fancy: Turn to one of the embedded languages (like perl).

So: Is it possible? Of course it is.